# Enable SSH in WSL system

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to enable SSH in my Ubuntu running in WSL2 system:

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

I get this error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

What does it mean and how can I enable ssh?

Comment: Since WSL does not use systemd you will need to launch the ssh as a service instead.  `sudo service ssh start`.

Answer (score 19):

**Update note #1**:  *Systemd is now supported on WSL2.  Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986) for details on how to enable it.  Once Systemd is enabled, the SSH server can now be started automatically with `sudo systemctl enable ssh` and queried with `sudo systemctl status ssh`.*

<strike>A few things to note when trying to use SSH on WSL2:</strike>

- <strike>As others have mentioned, since WSL does not yet support the `systemd` init system and infrastructure, you'll need to rely on other methods.  The WSL version of Ubuntu still provides the old `init.d` style scripts for most services.  So `sudo service ssh start` (or `restart`, or `status`, or `stop`, etc.) is what you'll use.</strike>

In addition to enabling SSH, however, you likely want to be able to connect to it from a remote system.  WSL2 runs in a VM with a virtual network interface that is NAT'd, so you won't be able to `ssh` into the WSL instance from any other machine on the network without additional effort.  WSL *does* provide automatic localhost forwarding, though, so you can `ssh` in from Windows on the same machine, or from another WSL instance on the same machine.

---

**Update note #2:** *The method below no longer works on recent WSL releases which are installed from the Microsoft Store.  The Store version of WSL has a known limitation that does not allow it to be started from a remote SSH session.  Leaving the answer here for now, but I'll update it soon with a different (less optimal, unfortunately, solution).*

If you just need terminal access to WSL from a remote machine, then here's a far easier solution:

- Install OpenSSH server in *Windows* ([instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)).
- Access your WSL instance remotely using `ssh -t windows_user@windows_host wsl`.  That just connects to the Windows host, allocates a pseudo-terminal with `-t`, and runs the `wsl` command using that pseudo-terminal.

If, on the other hand, you need *real* SSH access to the WSL instance, then the "usual answer" is fairly complicated still.  See [this Github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723) and thread and my summary of your general options for port forwarding [here](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833).

That's "in general" though.  For `ssh` we *can* make it easier by using an ssh server in both the Windows host *and* the WSL instance.  See a "short version" of this in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1647547/1210833) and (far) more details if you need them in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1622603/1210833).

The "far more details" answer also includes a solution to starting the ssh server remotely, since it won't automatically run at boot time under WSL.

Comment: This may have recently changed? I have just installed Debian WSL on Windows 10, ran `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and `sudo service ssh start`. A Windows firewall dialog prompted me to permit access for a port and I was immediately able to ssh from a remote machine. It also was already enabled on restart!

Comment: @blee Hmmm.  Maybe?  But I'm *suspecting* something else might be at play here.  First, `Get-Service |? { $_.Name -like "*ssh*" }` from PowerShell - Is the Windows OpenSSH server running?  Second, `wsl.exe -l -v` -- Is the WSL instance version 1 or 2?  Version 1 won't have any issues with port forwarding.  But if it really *is* WSL1, then I'd still be confused about why it's there on restart.

Comment: You're right about Debian openssh-server being there on restart, I must have tricked myself about that. Derp. PowerShell does not show any ssh server running and says my Debian WSL is version 1. Moreover, I think I'll follow your advice and install Windows ssh as I'd really like to be able to shut the machine off remotely anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For WSL you'll want to use the correct syntax:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

This will give you what you're looking for:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-05-22 19:54:00 JST; 3h 25min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 2129 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2137 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9127)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─2137 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

 5月 22 19:54:00 Carbon systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
 5月 22 19:54:00 Carbon sshd[2137]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
 5月 22 19:54:00 Carbon sshd[2137]: Server listening on :: port 22.
 5月 22 19:54:00 Carbon systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Comment: While the command you cite is correct, the output is not what you will receive on WSL.  On WSL, `service ssh status` uses the old `init.d` style scripts, so you'll just see `* sshd is running` or `sshd is not running` as the output of the command.

Comment: Late I know but this is exactly the output you get from WSL 2.

Answer (score -1):

**You should enable `dbus` it's more like port forwarding**

```
#enable dbus
sudo systemctl enable dbus
sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start
```

if the result is the same as the picture below then don't worry it's not a problem

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytxyc.png)

and then

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how `dbus` will help in this case.  AFAIK, the `ssh` service does not rely on it at all.